# How to install Python packages using Pip in Inno Setup

Tags: python, inno-setup

How to install Python libraries using **Pip** (for instance requests, jinja2, falcon etc)** in Inno Setup?

I know one method to install Python libraries using Pip in Inno Setup (just a sample code in the below):

**Inno Setup file:**

```
[Files]
FileName: "python_file.py";
```

**python_file.py**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["pip", "install", "requests"])
```

May I know, is there any other way to install Python libraries using Pip in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `pip` is a standalone executable, you can execute it as any other executable using the [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[Run]
Filename: "pip.exe"; Parameters: "install requests"; StatusMsg: "Installing requests..."
```

This will run `pip` as Administrator (if the installer is running as Administrator). That also means that `pip` has to be in system-wide `PATH`. If pip/Python was installed for specific user only, it won't work. Though then a question is, if your installer should be installing your Python-dependent application sysmte-wide, if the Python was not. Anyway, if you need to run `pip` for the current user only, add `Flags: runasoriginaluser`.